# How do I fix steppy graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to animate something but it turns out very jittery.
And when I look in the graph editor, it is like the picture below.

[image: graph]

I'm trying to set the value from -7 at the first frame to 7 at the last frame.
How do I make the graph linear or what must I do to make the animation smoother?

Thank you so much.

Comment: In the N panel (on the right of the Graph Editor) > Modifiers, have you given a Stepped modifier to your curve?

Comment: is the input value an integer by any chance?

Comment: @moonboots it has no modifiers

Comment: @Chris Yes it is. Do I have to change it, or how do I change it? Thank you

Comment: well, i think (it's just an assumption) you cannot animate an integer continuously...which makes sense, because you defined it as an integer. So either you accept that or you change the input value in the geometry nodes group node to a float value

Comment: @Chris That did it!  Thank you so much sir Chris!! -/|\-